# UIWebView focus on specific square

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

Is there a way in xcode to focus my UIWebView to a specific square view of a website?.

So, I display a predefined part of a website to be shown in my view. Without making the user scrolling over to that part of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to do this in Objective-C you could (on iOS 5 and above) access the `scrollView` property of `UIWebView`, and zoom/move the page accordingly.

However, it's probably going to be a much better strategy to have the webpage itself do this -you can access the viewport through javascript and adjust its zoom accordingly, and scrolling to a specific part of a webpage through JS is trivial.

Comment: Sounds good. Is it possible to lock scrolling? so that only what I want is visible to the user?

Comment: I think if you just set `scrollEnabled` on the `scrollView` property to `NO` you should be able to.

Comment: The thing is that I do not have control over the page that I want to display. That is why I chose to display it using UIWebView I'll try all what you suggest.

Comment: Do you have an example of evaluating a JS?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `ScrollView` property of `UIWebView` and scroll to desired position

```
- (void)scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)
```

Or You can do this using `JavaScript` by evaluating JavaScript string:

```
[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:JS];
```

Answer (score 1):

**This works perfectly for me:**

Make sure you set the view controller where you have your web view to be a `UIWebViewDelegate`, and declare this in the `@interface` of the header file (.h).

```
[yourWebView setDelegate:self];
```

Then, in the `webViewDidFinishLoad:` method, insert this code:

```
[yourWebView.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, yourPreferredScroll, 1, 1) animated:NO];
```